# android's api not working

Tags: php, android

i created a register service for my android app
the android side is working correct(i guess) and returns "failed"
this is my PHP code:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$User = json_decode($json);

function ConnectDatabase()
{
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "my_db");
    mysqli_set_charset($connect, "utf8");
    return ConnectDatabase();
}

$username = $User->user;
$password = $User->pass;

function AddUser($user, $pass)
{
    $connect = ConnectDatabase();
    if (!(trim($user) == "" || trim($pass) == ""))
    {
        $check = mysqli_query($connect, "select count(*) from usertable where Username='$user'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($check);
        if ($row[0] > 0)
        {
            return "usernameTaken";

        }
        else
        {
            $SQL = "INSERT INTO usertable(Username,Password) VALUES ('$user','$pass')";
            $query = mysqli_query($connect, $SQL);
            if ($query != "")
            {
                return "ok";
            }
            else
            {
                return "failed";
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return "badUsernameOrPassword";
    }
}

$status = AddUser($username, $password);
echo json_encode(["status"=>$status]);
```

checked the uri and its correct...you guys see any mistake?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PHP documentation for `mysqli_query` from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.query.php):

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Thus your code has to be:

```
if ($query != FALSE){
    return "ok";
}else{
    return "failed";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your php code, it should never return failed because `$query` will either be a `mysqli_result` object or `false` and never `""`. Without seeing your android code, it will be difficult to tell. But this PHP code will alway return `usernameTaken`, `badUsernameOrPassword` or `ok` (never will it show failed.) The problem definitely has to come from your android code if you are seeing "failed". Do you mind posting your Android code so I can help with it by updating my answer? You should also change:

```
if ($query != "")
{
   return "ok";
}
```

to

```
if (!$query)
{
    return "ok";
}
```